# Boost::GIL 'jpeglib.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, boost, boost-gil

```
#include <boost/gil/gil_all.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg_io.hpp>

int main()
{
  using namespace boost::gil;
  rgb8_image_t img;
  jpeg_read_image("test.jpg",img);
}
```

I included $BOOST_ROOT to VS 2010 project properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.

same error is defined in http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppCompileErrorJpeglibHnoSuchFileOrDirectory.htm
but declared solution did not resolve my problem.

Comment: You need to install a [JPEG library](http://www.ijg.org/).

Comment: hi @JoachimPileborg i couldn't figure out how to install to make it work with gil. Can you explain it?

Comment: i built jpeg library for vs 2010 by following instructions in .txt. now i get error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_start_decompress errors

Comment: http://www.dbuggr.com/andrew8062/compile-ijg-jpeg-library-libjpeg-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: vs setup include directory C:\libraries\jpeg-9 lib directory C:\libraries\jpeg-9\Release

Answer (score 26):

the jpeg library is missing perhaps?

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
```

^that solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

`sudo dnf install libjpeg-turbo-devel` on fedora.

Answer (score 0):

Install or bind a library with standard JPEG compatible API:

- JPEG
- JPEG-turbo
- MozJPEG
- etc

Here is an example: https://github.com/ohhmm/generator/blob/741e9921c6c7083d7126fb018d941939d60a6612/picture-pattern-generate/CMakeLists.txt#L5